# Access Request object from REST

Tags: java, web-services

Is it possible to access the Request object in a REST method under JAX-RS?

I just found out

```
@Context Request request;
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

On JAX-RS you must annotate a [Request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html) parameter with [@Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html):

```
 @GET  
 public Response foo(@Context Request request) {

 }
```

Optionally you can also inject:

- [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)
- [HttpHeaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html)
- [SecurityContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html)
- [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 18):

To elaborate on @dfa's answer for alternatives, I find this to be simpler than specifying the variable on each resource method signature:

```
public class MyResource {

  @Context
  private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

  @GET  
  public Response foo() {  
    httpRequest.getContentType(); //or whatever else you want to do with it
  }
}
```

Comment: Any of this above don't work when I try to invoke the REST api from Junit. The request comes as null.

Comment: This may not work in later versions of Dropwizard @DebaprasadJana - this was for Dropwizard 0.7.x

Comment: Are there any concurrency issues with this approach?

Comment: @Dragas every request to the application will have its own thread, so there will not be a problem with concurrency.

Comment: But controllers that contain `@Path` annotations are singletons, aren't they? Does that not mean that if your request takes long enough, eventually your thread will update with another requests metadata?

Comment: @Dragas I do not believe it automatically makes it a singleton. In my uses, each class is instantiated for each request. One would need to add another annotation to force it to be a singleton. Even then, I'm not sure that's possible for REST controllers. It's instance per request by default.