# How do I get the full request URL with host-name/ip of a rest call?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restful-url

I need to get the full url with the host name or IP address from a restful request  made to my rest service. Is there any way this can be done?

Similar to InetAddress ip = ip.getHostName(); in java.

Comment: [Refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043346/access-request-object-from-rest) on how to access request object in rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jersey you can do the following

```
String clientHost = req.getRemoteHost(); // req is HttpServletRequest
String clientAddr = req.getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked also found the below code which works:         <code>@GET
@Path("/test")
public Response test(@Context HttpContext context) {
    String url = context.getRequest().getAbsolutePath().getPath();
    String query = context.getRequest().getRequestUri().toASCIIString();
    String reqString = url + " + " + query;
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(reqString).build();
} </code>

Comment: This works but its not generic the result would differ if used on local machine for example http://localhost:8080/test wont return "localhost" instead it will return something like this "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" which is the IPv6 representation of local loopback address ::1 or ::1/128

Answer (score 1):

When you say InetAddress ip = ip.getHostName(); you will get the hostname of the machine where your rest service is running, to get the the name of the machine from where request is originated you will need to use something similar to request.getRemoteHost(); this value could be depend on the network environment of the machine from where request was originated.

to get full url please refer below post.
[What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UriInfo`, it will get you the *server-side* `URI`, not the *client-side* one.

If you want the client-side `URI`, you will have to use `HttpServletRequest`:

```java
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Response uriTest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) { 
    try {
        URI baseUri = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).toURI();
        System.out.println(baseUri.getHost());
        System.out.println(baseUri.getPort());
        return Response.ok(null).build();
    } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error building the base URI.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using **CDI** and **@Context**, similar to the comment by [Ashir Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4649121/ashir-khan) [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938746/530513), the requestContext or parts of the request context can be made available at run time. Many types can be bound by the **@Context** annotation and injected by the container, although it would be better to:

1. Reduce the visibility of the injected data as much as possible ie *bind to the method rather than the class* and
2. Reduce the amount of information injected as possible ie *bind the **UriInfo** if all you want is the baseUri rather than the full request context*.

Sounds like a lot, but is as simple as (a modification on) Ashir's code:

```
@GET
@Path("/test") 
// Look Ma, no hands!
public Response test(@Context javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo uriInfo) { 
  return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(uriInfo.getBaseUri()).build();
}
```

[See also this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29844320/530513)

Comment: This returns the uri (host port etc.) of the server not the client.

Comment: yes, that was the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `UriInfo` class and bind it using the `@Context` annotation, then at every request you can access the URI information like Hostname, Port, Request Path etc.

Here is an example -

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Response uriTest(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){ //helps you get all URI related information.
    System.out.println(uriInfo.getBaseUri().getHost());
    System.out.println(uriInfo.getBaseUri().getPort());
    return Response.ok(null).build();
}
```

You can read more about `URIInfo` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it's based on the jax-rs standard @Ashir Khan

Comment: This is absolutly not the correct answer, since it returns server information not the client information that we want in this question. Which is why the other answer is accepted.