# How to access header value passed while calling api in postman?

Tags: java, spring, postman, jersey, jax-rs

```
@POST
@Path("/id")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDetails(DetailsRequest detailsRequest) {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/ywgtS.png]

how to pull RedId from headers in POST call , need help on this

Comment: This is JAX-RS (probably Jersey) and not Spring MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that you are using JAX-RS, and that `DetailsRequest` inherit from `HttpServletRequest`, if you want to follow security good practices, you might use servlet filters, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224180/20161294 .
then use:

`String headerValue = detailsRequest.getHeaders("RefId");`